# In Rails, how to use Jquery after passing a rendered collection to a partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple todo list in Rails. The tutorials that I've seen tells me to create a migration just so that I can strike through each item to check them off. I don't see why I would need to bother the server just to have some words struck through, so I am trying to use jquery to do it. Here's the partial of my rendered collection:

```
#application.css.scss:

.stroked { 
  text-decoration: line-through;
 opacity: 0.4;
}

# _todo_item.html.erb

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
      $('p').toggleClass('stroked');
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="complete">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</div>

<div class="todo_item">
  <p><%= todo_item.content %></p>
</div>

<div class="trash">
  <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), 
    method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I can get the jquery to work outside of the partial, but I dont want all the content with p tags to be struck through, just that particular item.

Comment: How about `$('.todo_item  > p').toggleClass('stroked');` ?

Comment: That didn't seem to work either.

Comment: You can try moving the script outside partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing a combination of what Thanh and Shannon said, I've found my solution shown below:

```
# todo_lists/show.html.erb

<% i = 0 %>
<% @todo_list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.mark<%= i %>').on('click', function(){
        $('.line<%= i %>').toggleClass('stroked');
      });
    });
  </script>

  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="complete">
      <i class="fa fa-check mark<%= i %>"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="todo_item">
      <p class="line<%= i %>"><%= todo_item.content %></p>
    </div>

    <div class="trash">
      <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), 
        method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }  do %>
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      <% end %>
    </div> 
  </div>

  <% i += 1 %> 
<% end %>
```

Now each item can be struck/unstruck out individually without having to bother the server. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this`:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-check').on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('stroked');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: But I want to strike thru the text which is todo_item.content. "this" would only refer to the check icon. Weird thing is I can't even invoke simple inline JS on todo_item.content.

Comment: You can use something like `.parent()` e.g. `$(this).parent().toggleClass('stroked');`

Comment: That still won't capture todo_item.content, which is what I'm trying to change.

Comment: You can get the closest `p` tag with `$(this).closest("p").toggleClass('stroked');`. However a better idea is to have your classes numbered for each item e.g. `todo_item_1` so you can easily select that class